# mongodump command not found in the git bash shell

Tags: mongodb, shell, git-bash

I am using mongodb to dump some data into a temporary folder I made using the git bash shell

```
$mkdir -p ~/tmp/mongodump
```

I try to dump data into the folder using the following command

```
$mongodump -h (name of host server) -d (name of database) -o (name of the output destination folder)
```

The problem is that git bash tells me

```
bash: mongodump: command not found
```

How do I get mongodump to work?

Comment: Erm, what the heck is git bash supposed to be? Anyway, what OS are you using?

Comment: Can you execute the ```mongo``` command? If yes, try executing ```which mongo``` and check if mongodump is also in this folder.

Comment: Thanks for the help, got it working.  The problem was that I didn't have a path to my mongo bin folder where mongodump was.

Comment: @Pjryan Can you provide the solution as well so that others can find it useful